# Update select dropdown options with PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown made with select tag on HTML. 
I have the values on a PHP, this is the code:

---

**proveedordinamico.php**

```
<?php
require "config.php";
$distinct1 = "SELECT DISTINCT proveedor FROM techno_articulos";
$distinctquery1 = mysql_query($distinct1,$enlace);
while ($fila1 = mysql_fetch_array($distinctquery1)) {
echo '<option>' . $fila1['proveedor'] . '</option>';
}
?>
```

---

**index.php**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    <div id="billdesc">
    <select id="test" class="form-control">
      <option class="non" value="option1">Option1</option>
      <option class="non" value="option2">Option2</option>
        <div id="actualizarlistaproveedores"></div>
      <option class="editable" value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <input class="editOption" class="form-control" style="display:none;" id="test">
    <input type="button" onclick="alertaopciones()">

    <script>


        function refreshlistaproveedores(){
            $('#actualizarlistaproveedores').load('includes/proveedordinamico.php', function(){
               setTimeout(refreshlistaproveedores, 100);
            });
        }
        refreshlistaproveedores();

        function alertaopciones(){

            var alertados = document.getElementById("test").value;
            alert(alertados);
        }
     </script>




    <script>
    var initialText = $('.editable').val();
    $('.editOption').val(initialText);

    $('#test').change(function(){
    var selected = $('option:selected', this).attr('class');
    var optionText = $('.editable').text();

    if(selected == "editable"){
      $('.editOption').show();


      $('.editOption').keyup(function(){
          var editText = $('.editOption').val();
          $('.editable').val(editText);
          $('.editable').html(editText);
      });

    }else{
      $('.editOption').hide();
    }
    });</script>
</div>
</div>
```

The function with the load every 100ms doesn't work. Is there any way to print `<option>` with each value of PHP?

I hope you can help me, if you have any question about the code ask me!

Comment: The "<input type="button" onclick="alertaopciones()">" is for alert me about the value of the select, I hope you can understand what I'm doing ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your trying to accomplish but replace your function with this:

```
function refreshlistaproveedores(){
        $('#test').load('includes/proveedordinamico.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshlistaproveedores, 100);
        });
    }
```

And remove:

```
   <div id="actualizarlistaproveedores"></div>
```

Divs inside a select is not valid html

Comment: I want a select tag that refresh when a value is inserted. Also when input type "editOption" is selected, an input is showed to enter a custom value of a select. It works but only insert the things declared in PHP and I need to enter it manually in the PHP.